# Ubuntu 64bit Xen DomU Issues after upgrade from Karmic to Lucid

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, init.d, udevd

I was upgrading my servers today and it all went fine except the last machine which has the following issues:

**[Resolved using http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/upgrade-ubuntu-pre-10.04#post-1004-upgradefinal-steps]**

- No login prompt on console

  ```
  Done.
  Begin: Mounting root file system... ...
  Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ...
  Done.
  [    0.545705] blkfront: xvda: barriers enabled
  [    0.546949]  xvda: xvda1
  [    0.549961] blkfront: xvde: barriers enabled
  [    0.550619]  xvde: xvde1 xvde2
  Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ...
  Done.
  [    0.870385] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
  [    0.870449] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
  Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ...
  Done.
  Done.
  Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ...
  Done.
  ```

Also tried by pressing ENTER and CTRL+C many times, no use.

**Resolved: [/tmp was mounted as noexec, changing that fix it]:**

- I get errors when i try to re-install udev in single user mode:

  ```
  Unpacking replacement udev ...
  Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
  ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
  Processing triggers for man-db ...
  Setting up udev (151-12.1) ...
  udev start/running, process 1003
  Removing `local diversion of /sbin/udevadm to /sbin/udevadm.upgrade'
  update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

  Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
  update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-25-server
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/local-premount/fixrtc: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/local-premount/ntfs_3g: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/local-premount/resume: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/nfs-top/udev: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/panic/console_setup: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/init-top/all_generic_ide: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/init-top/blacklist: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/init-top/udev: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/init-bottom/udev: Permission denied
  /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /tmp/mkinitramfs_yuuTSc/scripts/local-bottom/ntfs_3g: Permission denied
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, check post for links on how to proceed.